# How to send the whole $POST array from the same page to an external php page?

Tags: php, html

I have one html page with on top php form validation to check if the fields are empty,  after that a html form and after that some html that displays a error message if fields are not filled in. The top of the form looks like:

```
  <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">
```

In the PHP that is on top of the page, I check to see if the input fields are empty.

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]==='POST')
{

          if($_POST["field1"]==""){
                    $errormessage = "field1 is not empty";

           }elseif($_POST["field2"]==""){
                 $errormessage = "field1 is not empty";
            }else{
            // if the fields are both filled in i want to send the form 
            //variables to mailing.php where are the variables are mailed

}
```

This is the html for the errorcode that is part of my page:

If both fields are filled I want to send the POST data to `mailing.php` where I can format the variables into a html email.

I know now with this code this is possible.

header('location:mailing.php?name=something?second=something')

But I have a lot of fields. Over 50.
Is there a way I can sent all the variables (the whole $POST) to the other page?
Just like you do with:

```
<form action="mail.php" method="post">
```

So in mail.php i can send a mail like this:

```
echo ' <html> <body>';
echo '<table class="aanvraagtabel" cellpadding="4">';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th> Field1: </th>';
echo '<td>'.$_POST["field1"].'</td>';
echo '</tr>';
echo '</table>';
echo ' </html> </body>';
```

Comment: Have you tried `cURL`?

Comment: You do _not_ want to forward the _client_ by means of redirection. Instead you want to make a _server internal_ post request to that other page. Take a look at the `curl` php extension for example.

Comment: If your fields satisfy your validation criteria, can you not just pass them to a function (do_mailing)?  If you pass them again via publicly accessible addresses unencrypted, the values can be mutated.  If you must temporarily store them between requests, sessions could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `header()` with `$_POST` because `$_POST` contains all posted fields

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]==='POST')
{
    if($_POST["field1"]==""){
        $errormessage = "field1 can not be empty.";
    }elseif($_POST["field2"]==""){
        $errormessage = "field2 can not be empty.";
    }else{
        header('location:mailing.php?' . http_build_query($_POST));
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note the OP could just swap out the header redirection for `require 'mailing.php';`.

Comment: you removed varName why

Comment: Note data can be tampered with after the validation using the location redirect method.

Answer (score 0):

The above solution will redirect you to another php page and you will have to listen to $_GET on mailing.php file.

The following function will execute another post request to the given url:

```
function postTo($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($_POST));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch); // Just in case needed. I think you dont really needs this because on the other script you just sends an email.
    curl_close ($ch);

    return $response;
}
```

to Integrate it into your code it should looks like this:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]==='POST')
{
    if ($_POST["field1"]=="") {
        $errormessage = "field1 is not empty";
    } elseif ($_POST["field2"]=="") {
        $errormessage = "field1 is not empty";
    } else {
        $url = $_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ."/mailing.php";
        $response = postTo($url);
    }
}
```

I do want to mention there are some other libraries out there that simplifies this code such as Guzzle. you might want to take a look.

Hope that helps,
Eden